# How to detect the rotation change when coming back to tableView from detailView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and DetailViewController that pops up when concrete row is selected. The problem is the tableView does not call "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" method when rotation is did in DetailViewController. It's logical, however I need to reload a table if orientation has changed.

I'm trying this code but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  if (self.interfaceOrientation != [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation){
    [self handleTableViewRotation];
  }
}
```

I'm assuming there should be some property that holds orientation of tableView that is independent of current device orientation property...

Comment: Just to clarify, the view controller HAS done the rotation, it's just that the notification methods (willRotate, didRotate) weren't called?

Comment: Yes. In fact it's logical that those notification methods weren't called because the actual rotation happened outside TBC - in DetailViewController. So, I was looking to solve that problem, and I have ended in using second solution provided by @ender. I have created a property in TBC that stores the tableViewController's last orientation, and I did comparison of it against current device orientation in TBC, in viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the most elegant solution is coding a protocol. Whenever your `DetailViewController` enters in a rotation callback, call `reloadData` method of your tableView.

Or... you can continue that way. In that case you have to store the tableViewController's last orientation as a instance var and compare it to the current. After that, **remember setting the new orientation**

**EDIT:** First declare a new Protocol.

```
@protocol RotationDelegate

    - (void) didRotate;

@end
```

In your DetailViewController.h:

```
#import RotationDelegate.h

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    id <RotationDelegate> rotationDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <RotationDelegate> rotationDelegate;
```

In DetailViewController.m:

```
@synthesize rotationDelegate;


-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    [rotationDelegate didRotate];

}
```

Now your ViewController that contains the tableView:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <RotationDelegate> {
    ...
}
```

And finally implement `didRotate` method and call `[yourTableView reloadData]` inside. Remember that you have to set the rotation delegate after init your DetailViewController.

Comment: I'm very little familiar with protocols. I do that I need sometimes to include delegate protocols and implement methods but I don't understand how to implement your suggested elegant solution. Could you give more details on that please?

Comment: Thanks @ender :) It looks like having a protocol and rotation delegate solution is similar to having just pure property (without using a protocol) like "tableViewController" on detailViewController and assigning it the value of tableViewController. I guess it would be a lazy solution :) It looks like implementing a protocol is some working convention to such task. But thank you a lot for clearing that ;)